# Responsive layout (portrait vs. landscape) for a heading, diagram, and text

Tags: css, css-float

I am struggling with how to specify in CSS (with media queries) a layout involving a heading, a diagram, and text, which needs differ depending on whether we're in portrait or landscape mode. It's targeting an iPhone-sized device, so space is at a premium.

In portrait mode, I want it to look like

```
HEADING

      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      XXXX         XXXX
      XXXX Diagram XXXX
      XXXX         XXXX
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

In landscape mode, I want it to look like

```
HEADING                    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                           XXXX         XXXX
Lorem ipsum dolor sit      XXXX Diagram XXXX
amet, consectetur          XXXX         XXXX
adipisicing elit,          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  
sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

The HTML is composed of an `h3` tag for heading, an `IMG` tag for the diagram, and one or more `p` tags for the text, currently in that order. I can re-arrange these any way I want, and/or add grouping `div`'s if necessary.

Assuming the HTML elements are ordered as heading/image/text, I get the portrait layout by default. For landscape, if I simply specify the diagram as `float: right;`, I get

```
HEADING                    

Lorem ipsum dolor sit      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
amet, consectetur          XXXX         XXXX
adipisicing elit,          XXXX Diagram XXXX  
sed do eiusmod tempor      XXXX         XXXX
incididunt ut labore et    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ore magna aliqua.
```

But I want to top of the diagram aligned with the heading, to avoid wasting blank space to the right of the heading.

I can also float the heading left, but then I get something crazy like

```
HEADING Lorem ipsum dolor  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
amet, consectetur          XXXX         XXXX
adipisicing elit,          XXXX Diagram XXXX  
sed do eiusmod tempor      XXXX         XXXX
incididunt ut labore et    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ore magna aliqua.
```

But if I add a CSS rules such as `p {clear: both; }` then the text jumps down to below the diagram as in

```
HEADING                    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                           XXXX         XXXX
                           XXXX Diagram XXXX  
                           XXXX         XXXX
                           XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I do not want to depend on scripting to move elements around.
Can someone think of a simple approach to accomplish what I want to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your solution of floating the image right and the heading left, but instead of `clear: both` on the `p` tag use `clear:left`.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4259) which does what you need, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think [Fluid Grid Layout](http://www.adobe.com/au/products/dreamweaver/features/fluid-grid-layout.html)
of Dreamweaver CS6 will help you to achieve this. You may find all the info you need in the link above or go straight to watch [this video](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs6-creative-cloud-feature-tour-for-web/fluid-grid-layout-in-dreamweaver-cs6/) from Adobe site to learn how it works. This is a short piece of info that you may want to know

> **Fluid Grid Layout helps you build pages that adjust to fit different screen sizes.You design the layouts visually, and Dreamweaver displays them in Live View. You can create pure CSS3 transitions to display animation effects on computers, smartphones, and tablets**